# Transform html into XSL

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I want to use an XSL style sheet to display a HTML form. However, I am not familiar with XSL. Below is the html:

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" name="form1">
  <h2 align="center">JPMorgan User:</h2>
  <table id="table1" cellspacing="5px" cellpadding="5%"
  align="left">
    <tr>
      <td align="left">User ID:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="User ID" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left">First Name:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="First Name" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left">Last Name:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Last Name" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="left">Email:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Email" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" align="center" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="Reset" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know of a free conversion tool I could use? Thanks.

Comment: This must be valid xml, i.e. use `<p/>` and `<input ... />`, lowercase and as closed tags. Also the `action=` attribute of the form looks suspicious, what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Hi Stefan, thank you for your input. The action= should return this form to a http request. I user will make a webservice request, and I am sending (well trying) this form back as the reply.

Comment: I have added end tags and changed the case to lowercase. However, this is still not working for me...

Comment: Your question is not clear. The stylesheet does not seem to require any input. Why then do you need it at all? -- Note also that an XSLT stylesheet must be a well-formed XML document. Your stylesheet still isn't.

Comment: Ok, thank you Michael. I will look at it some more.